# Chromium WebView does not exist (UnsupportedOperationException)

Tags: java, android, webview, admob

I am making a simple app with the aid of [this](http://kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html) tutorial, but am having trouble adding ads.
The game runs fine without them, but I get a Chromium WebView does not exist error and an UnsupportedOperationException error with ads (I'm not sure if one error is causing the other).

Here is my SampleGame class (the one that is called when the application starts)

```
package com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

import com.kilobolt.framework.Screen;
import com.kilobolt.framework.implementation.AndroidGame;

public class SampleGame extends AndroidGame
{
    public static String map;
    boolean firstTimeCreate = true;
    //
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")
        .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public Screen getInitScreen()
    {
        if(firstTimeCreate)
        {
            Assets.load(this);
            firstTimeCreate = false;
        }

        return new SplashLoadingScreen(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        getCurrentScreen().backButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //Assets.theme.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        //Assets.theme.pause();
    }
}
```

This is SampleGame's parent class that I have modified

```
package com.kilobolt.framework.implementation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame.R;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Audio;
import com.kilobolt.framework.FileIO;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Game;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Graphics;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Input;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Screen;

public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 480: 800;
        int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 800: 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getInitScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyGame");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
        screen.resume();
        renderView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();
        renderView.pause();
        screen.pause();

        if (isFinishing())
            screen.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        return graphics;
    }

    @Override
    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {

        return screen;
    }
}
```

Here is my main.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="480dp"
                         android:layout_height="75dp"
                         android:gravity="bottom"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9472185097153282/1248179452"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, here is my logcat output

```
08-24 05:38:37.130: D/dalvikvm(897): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 8% free 2162K/2340K, paused 149ms, total 150ms
08-24 05:38:37.130: I/dalvikvm-heap(897): Grow heap (frag case) to 2.972MB for 768016-byte allocation
08-24 05:38:37.260: D/dalvikvm(897): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 2912K/3092K, paused 124ms, total 124ms
08-24 05:38:38.080: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(897): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 5077534
08-24 05:38:38.220: I/Ads(897): Starting ad request.
08-24 05:38:38.280: I/Ads(897): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
08-24 05:38:38.360: E/WebViewFactory(897): Chromium WebView does not exist
08-24 05:38:38.370: E/WebViewFactory(897): Chromium WebView does not exist
08-24 05:38:38.370: D/AndroidRuntime(897): Shutting down VM
08-24 05:38:38.370: W/dalvikvm(897): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a60d70)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897): Process: com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame, PID: 897
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame/com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame.SampleGame}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.createWebView(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:41)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2058)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2116)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3461)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3517)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:498)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:475)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:455)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:444)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:434)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ex.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ex.a(Unknown Source)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.a(Unknown Source)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.a(Unknown Source)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame.SampleGame.onCreate(SampleGame.java:27)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
08-24 05:38:38.660: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  ... 11 more
08-24 05:38:40.360: W/dalvikvm(897): threadid=5: spin on suspend #1 threadid=13 (pcf=0)
08-24 05:38:40.360: D/dalvikvm(897): Temporarily moving tid 914 to fg (was 0)
08-24 05:38:40.360: D/dalvikvm(897): Temporarily raised priority on tid 914 (10 -> 0)
08-24 05:38:40.450: W/dalvikvm(897): threadid=5: spin on suspend resolved in 1148 msec
08-24 05:38:40.450: D/dalvikvm(897): Restored policy of 914 to 0
08-24 05:38:40.450: D/dalvikvm(897): Restored priority on 914 to 10
08-24 05:38:45.900: D/dalvikvm(897): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 272K, 12% free 3154K/3560K, paused 113ms, total 1199ms
08-24 05:38:45.950: D/dalvikvm(897): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads2143539119.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
08-24 05:38:49.050: D/dalvikvm(897): DexOpt: --- END 'ads2143539119.jar' (success) ---
08-24 05:38:49.070: D/dalvikvm(897): DEX prep '/data/data/com.harryhochwarter.frugalfarminggame/cache/ads2143539119.jar': unzip in 1ms, rewrite 3112ms
```

Please let me know if I need to include any additional code or information!

Comment: `08-24 05:38:38.280: I/Ads(897): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.`

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here:

1. As your log says you have an outdated version of Google Play Services
2. As your log says you need to "set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad."
3. And you are calling #setContentView fro your Activity twice. Once in the Activity and once in the parent Activity. This is going to cause your grief.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Is it better for me to call #setContentView in my activity or the parent activity?

Comment: I would do it in your Activity as you have more visibility.